# Using JS promises/generator to implement simple semaphore

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator, semaphore

I'm trying to use NodeJS to allow only 2 tasks to access a piece of code concurrently (this could be for example accessing an API but is simulated below with the `yield wait(2000)`. I'm using the `co` package to make it work with generators and promises rather than callbacks, but the code below is only allowing 1 at a time instead of 2 to access the code between `yield semPromise(sem)` and `sem.leave()`.

The semaphore package is the NodeJS one (https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore) and has a `take` and `leave` function to enter and leave the guarded code section.

I'm trying it with ES6 Promises below.

```
var sem = require('semaphore')(2);

function wait(millis) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){resolve()}, millis);
    });
}

function semPromise(sem) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sem.take(function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

co(function *main() {
    for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        yield semPromise(sem);
        console.log('enter' + i);
        yield wait(2000);
        console.log('done' + i);
        sem.leave();
    }
});
```

But if I replace

```
        yield wait(2000);
        console.log('done' + i);
        sem.leave();
```

With

```
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('done');
            sem.leave();
        }, 2000);
```

It seems to work. But if I'm trying to avoid callbacks and learn how to use Promises correctly, how can I do it?

Comment: There is a huge difference between those code snippets; the other fires 10 timeouts in parallel while the generator version waits for 1 timeout to finish before even starting the next. You need to be careful with generators in order not to write slow sequential code.

Comment: How does the generator version behave that way? Doesn't the `yield wait(2000)` run asynchronously?

Comment: @user779159 no, the whole point of using generators is that the `yield wait(2000)` pauses the generator. Unlike normal functions generators can yield control and effectively "pause" while the actual IO is still asynchronous.

Comment: @user779159 it runs asynchronously in that the whole program isn't frozen but obviously it blocks the generator